# async.each nested in async.waterfall

Tags: node.js, mongodb, async.js

I have recently started using async api. Now my requirement is to perform a join on 3 collections
namely fields, scripts and statements. fields can have multiple scripts, and scripts can have multiple statements.

here is what I have tried so far:(to join Fields collection with scripts)

```
// Array to hold async tasks
var asyncTasks = [];

async.waterfall([
    function(callback){
        // fetches fields based on some Id and it returns 2 fields
        db.fields.find({entity_id: mongojs.ObjectId("54440a448bbbcbb4070131ab")}, function (err, fields) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(fields, null, 2));
            callback(null, fields);
        })
    },
    function(arg1, callback){
        // arg1 now equals fields        
        arg1.forEach(function(eachField){
            asyncTasks.push(function(callback){
                db.scripts.find({fieldId: eachField._id.valueOf()}, function(err, scripts) {
                    // Async call is done then alert via callback
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(scripts, null, 2));
                    callback(null, scripts);
                });
            });
        });


        // Now we have an array of functions doing async tasks
        // Execute all async tasks in the asyncTasks array
        async.parallel(asyncTasks, function(err, results) {
            // All tasks are done now
            console.log("Scripts" + JSON.stringify(results, null, 2));
            callback(null, "done");
        });

    }
], function (err, result) {
        console.log(result);
});
```

---

```
// for the above code here is what i get the output
[
  {
    "_id": "54440a548bbbcbb4070131ac",
    "name": "t1",
    "type": "String",
    "entity_id": "54440a448bbbcbb4070131ab"
  },
  {
    "_id": "54447f1d20c103981fa1a27c",
    "name": "t2",
    "type": "String",
    "entity_id": "54440a448bbbcbb4070131ab"
  }
]
size of array 2
[]
[]
Scripts[
  [],
  []
]
done
```

---

The above output doesn't print any scripts even though there are 2 scripts in database. My database is is in MongoDB, and i am using NodeJs, MongoJS api. why is db.scripts.find() returning empty array?
Any help is appreciated

I tested this piece of code to see if scripts returning the o/p. Please find below my code

```
 test2();
    function test2(){

        var getScriptFunction = function(eachField, doneCallback){
            if(eachField !== undefined) {
                var fieldId = eachField;
                console.log(fieldId);
                db.scripts.find({fieldId: fieldId}, function (err, result) {
                    // Async call is done, alert via callback
                    doneCallback(null, result);
                });
            }
        }
        // The array is the id of fields
        async.map(["54440a548bbbcbb4070131ac", "54447f1d20c103981fa1a27c"], getScriptFunction, function (err, results) {
            // Square has been called on each of the numbers
            // so we're now done!
            if (err){
                console.log("error!" + err);
            } else {
                console.log("printed from helper function \n" + JSON.stringify(results, null, 2));
            }
        });
    }
```

---

This is the o/p of the above code to fetch scripts ran individually

```
printed from helper function
[
  [
    {
      "_id": "54440a678bbbcbb4070131ad",
      "name": "s1",
      "fieldId": "54440a548bbbcbb4070131ac"
    },
    {
      "_id": "544af260eb7a486824a5c306",
      "name": "s2",
      "fieldId": "54440a548bbbcbb4070131ac"
    }
  ],
  []
]
```

---

This is how fields look like (db.fields.find().pretty())

```
[
  {
    "_id": "54440a548bbbcbb4070131ac",
    "name": "t1",
    "type": "String",
    "entity_id": "54440a448bbbcbb4070131ab"
  },
  {
    "_id": "54447f1d20c103981fa1a27c",
    "name": "t2",
    "type": "String",
    "entity_id": "54440a448bbbcbb4070131ab"
  }
]
```

Comment: Try putting `eachField._id` directly in your find query instead of `eachField._id.valueOf()`. The query will only match properly if you give it a real `ObjectId` instance.

Comment: It will not work because the fieldId is saved as a string value and not ObjectId.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and still no luck

Comment: Well the types have to match up in order for the query to match the document. Double check both the data in mongodb and the types in your query in your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem. there were 2 problems (1) I was having the same name for callback functions i.e. inner and outer callback nested within each other. (2) I had to use toString() and not valueOf()